# reading character from string and setting it in textviews

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android and java programming.. I want read my string character by character.. in such a way that first character should be set to some text view and second character to other text view.. my string do not contain more than two characters.I have tried charAT() method but no result Kindly have a look at the code.

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {

     val1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(quotient3.getText()));
     val2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(divisor.getText()));
     result = val1 * val2;

     val = Integer.toString(result);

     if(val.length()==1){
       aftersub2dividend2.setText(val.charAt(0)); //here is the issue
       aftersub2dividend1.setText(val.charAt(1)); //here is the issue
     }
     else {
       aftersub2dividend1.setText(val.charAt(0)); //here is the issue
       aftersub2dividend2.setText(val.charAt(1)); //here is the issue
     }
   }
  },3000);
```

Comment: You need to provide more information such as the **Activity code** your current snippet belongs to, and also the **layout xml** for the Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
aftersub2dividend1.setText(String.valueOf(val.charAt(0)));
```